# Skip to click Accept when prompt while running Windows offline update

Tags: windows-update

how can I skip to click acceptance while initialize the below Windows offline update

start "" /wait "%~dp0windows10.0-kb5000808-x86_422af16076c0cfbf162e232c35f6403755efb385.msu"

Can I add /accepteula at the end ??

Answer (score 0):

`wusa` can do quiet installs of msu files via:

```
wusa.exe c:\path\to\update.msu /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: Tks, but this does not show the progress of update !!

Comment: @VB88 If you want to see the whole thing, then run it without `/quiet`. If you just want the window to stay open while it runs, then run `start /wait wusa.exe [...]`.

Comment: @VB88 There is not a command-line option to only accept the eula (when there is one). The only alternatives I've seen are some really bizarre examples of extracting the .msu to different file types and installing them separately or editing the manifest. But I don't think those are what you're looking for